# VBA Copy Cells + Formatting without using the clipboard

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I'm trying to copy cells from one sheet to another without copying stuff to the clipboard but it must copy the formatting across.

Here are the ways I've tried at the moment, any ideas how to accomplish my needs?

```
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Nas").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

'Option 1, works but it's using the clipboard :/
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Nas").Range("A" & 6 & ":F" & LastRow).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("A" & 6 & ":F" & LastRow).Offset(-5, 0).PasteSpecial

'Option 2, works but doesn't take formatting (ie text, general, time, date... etc)
Set Src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Nas").Range("A" & 6 & ":F" & LastRow)
Set Dst = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("A" & 6 & ":F" & LastRow).Offset(-5, 0).Resize(Src.Rows.Count, Src.Columns.Count)
Dst.Value = Src.Value

'Option 3, works but doesn't take formatting (ie text, general, time, date... etc)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("A" & 6 & ":F" & LastRow).Offset(-5, 0) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Nas").Range("A" & 6 & ":F" & LastRow).Values
```

Comment: Beyond an intellectual exercise, what is the point of enumerating through the source cell's properties (and subproperties) to transfer them to the destination cell when all relevant information is carried across with the clipboard quite handily? What about internal sub-subproperties (e.g. the second word in a string is red and italicized)?

Comment: I would just use: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Nas").Range("A" & 6 & ":F" & LastRow).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("A" & 6 & ":F" & LastRow).Offset(-5, 0)`. There will not be a clash with that.

Comment: Rory how would I copy over the cell width with this method?

Comment: @Jeeped , when many vba script are running simultaneously using clipboard to copy creates fast a big mess. if you have solution for that i will be happy to use copy/paste as it s much easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code defines the *formatting* to be carried across as *"text, general, time, date... etc"*. While the *number formatting* (a subset of the **Properties** of a cell) can easily be accommodated, delving further into enumerating the vast number of properties and subproperties of a `Cells` object is counter-productive when all relevant (*non-default*) properties can be carried across easily with a copy/paste operation using the clipboard.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Nas")
  LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("A6:F" & LastRow).Offset(-5, 0) = _
    .Range("A6:F" & LastRow).Value
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("A6:F" & LastRow).Offset(-5, 0).NumberFormat = _
    .Range("A6:F" & LastRow).NumberFormat
End With
```

Note that transferring the value of the cell across is performed with `.Value` or `.Value2` not `.Values`.

I have seen this question popup occasionally and IMHO, the source of the question is likely a) a teacher that thinks this is a cutesy way to get students to appreciate just how many properties, subproperties and internal sub-subproperties a `Range.Cells` object ([Range Members (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197454(v=office.15).aspx)) contains or b) some idiot with a fresh MBA that wants to prove they are smarter than the IT department. Enumerating through every possible formatting property a cell could contain is just a fool's errand (again IMHO) when the clipboard is available.

If you do attempt this yourself, don't forget Conditional Formatting and Comments, both of which can easily be attributed as part of a cell's formatting.

Comment: A problem with using the clipboard is if you have multiple vba documents doing things they can clash also if you copy something while the macro is running again you can overright the clipboard...

I forgot to mention I need conditional formatting too. I found a way around it by copying as it's not using copy and paste but it is really inefficient.

Why should I use `.value` or .`value2` over `.values`?

Comment: @Ryflex This will only work to copy number formats if the NumberFormat of all cells in the source range are the same.

Comment: @Ryflex - At the risk of falling down a rabbit hole, *which* conditional formatting rule? There could conceivably be several. Programmatically speaking it would be better to adjust the `.RefersTo` property of the CF rule than define a new CF rule based upon the original.

Comment: @Ryflex - Primarily, you should use `.Value` or `Value2` because `.Values` is not a property of a `Range.Cells` object. If you choose to use the latter you will receive `Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method`.

Comment: @Ryflex - If you are using something like [RDP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383015(v=vs.85).aspx) to remote into a server or workstation to run your VBA and keep it minimized, disable the shared clipboard so your own desktop activities do not interfer with the VBA's operation.